# Длинная арифметика и функция getchar()

Tags: c

При вводе больших значений я решил использовать функцию getchar(). Программа не выдаёт никаких результатов. Правильно ли я использую функцию getchar() Если правильно, то в чём проблема?
Программа выглядит вот так.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {

    int a[100], b[100], c[100], i = 0, j, m = 0;
    int n = 0, d = 0;

    while((n = getchar()) != EOF) {
        a[i] = n;
        i++;
    }

    while((d = getchar()) != EOF) {
        b[m] = d;
        m++;
    }

    for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        c[j] = a[j] + b[j];
    }

    for(j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
        printf("%d", c[j]);
    }

    printf("%d\n", c[j - 1]);
    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @MahovIV, а что Вы хотели получить?

Данный код  записывает в массив ASCII коды считываемых **символов**, которые Вы набираете на клавиатуре (включая коды пробелов, табуляций, перевода строки (`\n`) и возврата каретки (`\r`) (т.к. судя по всему у Вас винда (*очень плохо для обучения*)).

Завершать ввод каждой "порции" (массива) надо ^Z (кстати, этот код тоже запишется в массив).

--

Подозреваю, что Вам просто нужен код для ввода заданного количества целых в массив.

Так об этом и спросите.

--

Да, уж извините, но Ваш стиль форматирования кода лично мне решительно не нравится.

Comment: @avp: переформатировал :-)

Answer (score 3):

getchar() - не совсем подходящая функция. Она запрашивает только 1 символ и дальше требует ввода Enter. Надеяться на то, что она будет брать последующие цифры из буфера тоже не стоит. Запросить длинное число лучше сначала в виде строки, а потом сделать преобразования, пример:

```
int count; // для длины строки
int i; // щечики
int longNumber[100]; // длинное число
char tmp[100]; // буфер для длинного числа
gets (tmp); // запрашиваем длинное число
count = strlen(tmp); // определяем длину введенного числа

// перенос в массив longNumber(int)
for (i=0; i<count; ++i) {
    if     (tmp[i] == '1') longNumber[i] = 1;
    else if(tmp[i] == '2') longNumber[i] = 2;
    else if(tmp[i] == '3') longNumber[i] = 3;
    else if(tmp[i] == '4') longNumber[i] = 4;
    else if(tmp[i] == '5') longNumber[i] = 5;
    else if(tmp[i] == '6') longNumber[i] = 6; // возможно есть что умнее, не искал
    else if(tmp[i] == '7') longNumber[i] = 7; // т.к задача получить массив целых чисел
    else if(tmp[i] == '8') longNumber[i] = 8; // с цифрами длинного числа
    else if(tmp[i] == '9') longNumber[i] = 9;
    else if(tmp[i] == '0') longNumber[i] = 0;
    else {/* тут говорим об ошибке ввода */}
}

// вывод длинного числа (теперь он хранится в массиве longNumber)
for (int i=0; i<count; ++i) {
    printf("%i", longNumber[i]);
}
return 0;
```

требуется библиотека string.h

Comment: индусы одобряют.

Comment: О боже, я-то думал, что такой код — глупый прикол с лурка. Дмитрий Анатольевич, попробуйте `tmp[i] - '0'`, вы будете приятно удивлены.

Comment: @VladD, возможно человек стремится к какой-то *абсолютной* переносимости исходного кода (т.е. что подразумевает его работоспособность даже с кодировкой (гипотетической), в которой коды десятичных цифр неизвестным образом разбросаны по кодовой таблице).

Но если такой паранойей не заморачиваться, то достаточно вспомнить о наличии `isdigit()` из `<ctype.h>` и то, что коды цифр последовательно возрастают.

@dmitmedv,

    int digit, code;
    ....
    if (isdigit(code))
        digit = code - '0';

Именно так все обычно поступают.

Comment: @avp: Человек должен либо спросить у старших товарищей, либо проконсультироваться со [стандартом](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Параграф 5.2.1.3 прямо заявляет:

> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

То есть коды символов, соответствующих цифрам, последовательны, это гарантирует стандарт.